# React Native - this.state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native that component that looks as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";
import SmsAndroid  from 'react-native-get-sms-android';

var filter = {
    box: 'inbox', // 'inbox' (default), 'sent', 'draft', 'outbox', 'failed', 'queued', and '' for all
    // the next 4 filters should NOT be used together, they are OR-ed so pick one
    read: 1, // 0 for unread SMS, 1 for SMS already read
    // _id: 1234, // specify the msg id
    // address: '+1888------', // sender's phone number
    // body: 'How are you', // content to match
    // the next 2 filters can be used for pagination
    indexFrom: 0, // start from index 0
    maxCount: 10, // count of SMS to return each time
};

export default class App extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {messages : {}, count: 0}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(" => Component is mounted")

    SmsAndroid.list(JSON.stringify(filter), (fail) => {
            console.log("Failed with this error: " + fail)
        },
        (count, smsList) => {
            console.log('Count: ', count);
            console.log('List: ', smsList);
            var arr = JSON.parse(smsList);

            this.setState({
              messages:arr,
              count:count
            })

            arr.forEach(function(object){
                console.log("Object: " + object);
                console.log("-->" + object.date);
                console.log("-->" + object.body);
            })
        });

  }

  componentWillUnMount () {
    console.log("Component will be unmounted")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text className="imp">{this.state.count}</Text>
        <Text className="imp">{typeof(this.state.messages)}</Text>
        {Object.keys(this.state.messages).map(function(key) {
          <Text className="imp">{this.state.messages[key]}</Text>
        })}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imp : {
    color:'#e74c3c'
  },
});
```

That said, the code works when I do this

```
<Text className="imp">{this.state.count}</Text>
<Text className="imp">{typeof(this.state.messages)}</Text>
```

but it fails when I try to loop over the messages

```
{Object.keys(this.state.messages).map(function(key) {
  <Text className="imp">{this.state.messages[key]}</Text>
})}
```

It fails with the following message

[image]

Can you please let me know what is wrong in my code ?

Thanks
Gagan

Comment: use arrow function here: `Object.keys(this.state.messages).map((key) => {....})`

Answer (score 0):

You create an anonymous function where `this` keyword will point to Object which is this anonymous function:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.messages).map(function(key) {
    <Text className="imp">{this.state.messages[key]}</Text>
})}
```

I see you can use arrow function, so change it to:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.messages).map((key) => {
    <Text className="imp">{this.state.messages[key]}</Text>
})}
```

Arrow function will use context in which it is defined.

More on "this" and functions in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Funkcje_strzalkowe).